# Redux dispatch or react-navigation for passing params?

Tags: react-native, redux

Is it better to pass params from one screen to another with redux dispatch or with react-navigation ?

**Redux way:**

Passing params (screen 1)

```
dispatch({
  type: PARAMS_TYPE,
  payload: {param1, param2}
});
```

Getting params (screen 2)

```
const {params} = this.props;
```

**React-navigation way:**

Passing params (screen 1)

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("Screen2",{param1, param2});
```

Getting params (screen 2)

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.param1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Redux in your Application than better way to do this is through Redux. This is because Redux stores complete state of an application in a single store which you can access from any component using props. React-navigation will make this task very complex and difficult to maintain if the Application is complex.